# Movie time from QTVisualContext given CVTimeStamp in CAOpenGLLayer rendering method?

Tags: core-animation, quicktime, core-video

I'm using the standard CoreVideo Display Link + QTVisualContext to render a QuickTime movie into an `NSOpenGLView` subclass. I would now like to synchronize a timeline view with movie playback. The timeline view is implemented as a layer hosting view, hosting a `CAOpenGLLayer` subclass that renders the timeline. I chose this architecture because the `CAOpenGLLayer` gets a `CVTimeStamp` for rendering. I thought that I could use this time stamp to get the current movie time from the QTVisualContext.

The only way I've found to get the movie time from a CVTimeStamp is to copy the QTVisualContext into a CVImageBuffer (using `QTVisualContextCopyImageForTime`) and then retrieve the movie time from the CVImageBuffer's `kCVBufferMovieTimeKey` attachment. Obviously, this seems like a little overkill since I don't need the image. Furthermore, the documentation for `QTVisualContextCopyImageForTime` indicates that asking for a time before the a previous call is not allowed. Since I can't guarantee the order of events between the CoreAnimation thread and the CoreVideo display link thread, I've run into a dead end.

It seems that `CVDisplayLinkTranslateTime` should be able to translate the CVTimeStamp I get in the `CAOpenGLLayer` rendering method into a movie time and movie time base, but I'm not sure how to relate this (Display Link) time to the QuickTime movie's time. I don't necessarily know when the movie's time 0 is relative to the Display Link movie time.

So, is there a way to get the movie time for a CVTimeStamp directly from the QTVisualContext (or anywhere else in the QTMovie->QTVisualContext->Display Link->...) pathway?

Comment: Hey Barry. I'm confused as to what you're trying to do. Why can't you just query the QTMovie's currentTime during playback instead?

Comment: @Matt - my understanding is that the movie's currentTime may not reflect the movie time for the frame that is being rendered when called from a Core Video Display Link callback or Core Animation rendering thread.

Comment: Have you looked at QTVisualContextSetImageAvailableCallback? It takes a callback function with the following signature: static void MyQTVisualContextImageAvailableCallback(QTVisualContextRef visualContext, const CVTimeStamp *timeStamp, void *refCon). This would provide you the timestamp and visual context when an image is available without having to copy the image, wouldn't it? (http://bit.ly/ahGnif). According to the comments in the code it's not necessary when using a display link, but it seemed like it might match what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question got a down vote. If there's something that needs clarifying, please let me know; I would *love* to give the bounty to someone!

Comment: @Matt The ImageAvailableCallback is conceptually like the Display Link callback. Unfortunately, it doesn't let me convert an arbitrary CVTimeStamp to a movie time.

Comment: Sorry Barry. I would be interested to know how you solved this when you do. Unfortunate that the Apple Engineers on the QT mailing list are so quiet. Seems like they should be able to answer something like this easily. Maybe bump it there and see if anyone responds? Best Regards.